# how to use a loop assigning values to inputs depending on another input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the value in "master" is even, like 8 I would like that the inputs "bla" would receive 2 each one, if number is odd like 7, the values ​in "bla" would be:  2, 2, 2, 1, 0 and so.  I'm trying with this, but the result is undefined

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var x = $("#master").val();
var z = 0 ;
var i ;
for (i = 0; i <= x ; i++) {
z += x[i];
 }

$("#master").change(function(){
   $('.bla').val( z ) ;        
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="master" value="8">

<input class="bla" value="">
<input class="bla" value="">
<input class="bla" value="">
<input class="bla" value="">
```

Comment: Can you reword your question? The instructions on how the input affects the output are currently unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the results you want you need more logic than you currently have. At least the way your question is worded. First issue is that your initial z value updating only updates once so when you update master the second time, you are not going to get the value you expect.

Next, you are trying, from what I understand, to basically break a number done into 2's a 1 and 0. So to do this you need way more logic to check the values than what you are currently doing. Below, if the value is > 1 we need to append a 2. Otherwise use the value of x. We then decrement x by the value we appended to bla.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    updateBla();
    $("#master").change(function(){
        updateBla();
    });
    
    function updateBla(){
        let x = $('#master').val();
        let blahs = document.getElementsByClassName('bla');
        for(let i = 0; i < blahs.length; i++){
            let val = x > 1 ? 2 : x;
            blahs[i].value = val;
            x = x - val;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="master" value="8">

<input class="bla" value="">
<input class="bla" value="">
<input class="bla" value="">
<input class="bla" value="">
```

Comment: How wold change this code if  ."#master"=8 and each one of the 8 ".bla"  the value where = 2 if if  ."#master"=7, then  7  ".bla" =2 and the last one = 0 and so.?

Comment: Not sure what you mean mate. That is exactly what this code does?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're trying to index a integer which, as @Sachintha Sampath has pointed out, doesn't really have an index with a value other than the 0th index. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#master").change(function(){
        var x = $("#master").val();
        var z = [];
        for (; x > 0; x -= 2) {
            z.push(x >= 2 ? 2 : 1)
        }

        $('.bla').each(function(index) {
            $(this).val(z[index])
        })
     });
});
```

NOTE: this code can only display numbers in your format up till 8 in which case there aren't enough inputs to continue displaying the rest of the number.

Answer (score -1):

```
    var z="";
    var x=9;
    var c=0;
    c=Math.floor(x/2);
    if(x%2==0){
      for (i = 0; i <c ; i++) {
        z +=" 2";
      }
    }else {
       for (i = 0; i <c ; i++) { 
           z +=" 2";
          }
     z+=" 1   0"
    }
   console.log(z);
```

Comment: I didn't explain right, I mean the value en each one of the "bla" must be just 2 if "master" is even but your code result "2,2,2,2" in each one